# PIG Latin script for Database access

Tags: database, hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to implement a surrogate key generator using PIG.
I need to persist the last generated key in a Database and query the Database for the next available key.

Is there any support in PIG to query the Database using ODBC?
If yes, please provide guidance or some samples.

Comment: Take a look at Sqoop.  Your pig script can generate everything needed except the key.  Then take the pig output and load it into the database using Sqoop and have the key get added automatically by the database.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not answering your question directly, but this is not something you want to be doing. For a few reasons:

- Your MapReduce job is going to hammer your database as a single performance chokepoint (you are basically defeating the purpose of Hadoop).
- With [speculative execution](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#tolerence), you'll have the same data get loaded up twice so some unique identifiers won't exist when one of the tasks gets killed.

I think if you can conceivably hit the database once per record, you can just do this surrogate key enrichment without MapReduce in a single thread.

Either way, building surrogate keys or automatic counters is not easy in Hadoop because of the shared-nothing nature of the thing.